# Any good replacement for Google Chrome for Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, google-chrome, chromium

I've been using Google Chrome for years on my old Windows XP box. I don't like IE8 which crashes all the time and is not compatible with many sites. However, Chrome dropped support of XP and Vista since Chrome 50. I am stuck with Google Chrome 49 which will no longer receive any more security updates.

I wonder if there is any other browser based on Chromium or Blink which continues to support XP. Thanks for comments.

Comment: If you're concerened about security updates, you would have changed the OS by now. Because MS droped support for XP long time ago.

Comment: You may try [Brave](https://brave.com/downloads.html), but it sounds like it's for for Windows 7+.

Comment: Also see..https://vivaldi.com/

Comment: and....http://www.maxthon.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try Slimjet from http://www.slimjet.com . The current version Slimjet 10 is based on Chromium 50 and supports XP and Vista. It syncs all your bookmarks via your google account automatically just like Google Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

- [Epic](https://www.epicbrowser.com/) - based on Chromium which is focused on user privacy
- [Torch](http://torchbrowser.com/) - a feature rich web browser with lots of customizable tweaks

For full list, check [WebKit-based/Chromium web browsers at Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_web_browsers#WebKit-based).

See also: [Web-browser for heavy browsing, alternative to Chrome](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/31811/3474)